# How to use the Windows 10 magnifier on 1 screen only

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, magnifier

I have found the magnifier functionality in windows 10 incredibly useful to make text more legible on dimmed screens. However, I would prefer if the full-screen version would only be active on ONE of my screens (as I am using a three-screen setup).
The settings don't appear to directly provide for this. Is there a way to get this to work, or is there alternate functionality I could use? The invert colors option has in particular proved useful.

Answer (score 0):

Even after 4 years, I can't work out how to do it with Windows Magnifier, but there is another Microsoft tool which zooms only one window. It's ZoomIt by SysInternals
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/zoomit

ZoomIt doesn't support screen smoothing so things do get a little jagged, and because it does screen scraping there is a little lag / latency. But it gives you other benefits like the ability to draw on the screen.